Can you recover previously deleted info from file after file is securely deleted?
I have found information online about deleting and recovering entire files, but not about this specific situation:
Let's say I have a saved Word document in Windows that has 2 paragraphs of text. I open this document and delete the first paragraph, then I save the file. Later, I delete the entire document file, but only this document file, using a Secure Erase tool.
Assuming I have not run this Secure Erase tool against all free space on the drive(s), is it possible to recover the first paragraph that was no longer part of the document when I securely erased it?
Edit -
I notice that this question has been considerably edited. English is not my first language! So may be the original question did not convey it correctly.
I know the way HDDs and SSDs work are entirely different, so if it's easy with one and harder with another, the answer can include those intricacies.
MS Word is just an example, it may be any other file from any other application.
I guess the implicit questions are

When you delete some data from a file and save it, does the deleted data reside somewhere (by chance if not overwritten) as random 1's and 0's on the storage?
During recovery, can it be linked back to the file?
Is Securely Deleting a single file (in question) enough, are we leaving behind previously deleted info somewhere on the free space?


[Edit] your question to indicate if the file is stored on a mechanical HDD or a SSD.

I won't say its impossible, but Ms office ~ files get deleted after a successful save or application exit, so its likely that the file with the first paragraph was removed at that time.

People will ask for more specifics to answer the question. But let me add in general there are no guarantees from an operating system, file system, or hardware storage device for how they deal with deleted data. A person's system could potential save a full copy of the file every single time there is an edit/save. And potentially all those many versions of the file would be intact within "free space" of the storage device - not accessible normally, but easily accessible to someone reading "raw data". I don't know any systems that work that way, but that is an extreme example.

The answer I have posted answers your question, including the update/edit you've made. It depends, and the correct thing to do in order to mitigate this chance is to clear temp files and wipe the free space on your drive.

I think the answer is "it depends".
It mostly depends on whether the modified file was saved back to the same space on the storage device. It also depends on what sort of file recovery tools and efforts are employed to attempt to recover this data. Finally, it depends on whether the data was cached to temporary locations during the editing process.
If the file was written back to the same location on the drive, and the new paragraph 1 was approximately the same length (takes up the same amount of space on the storage device) then the Secure Erase process would have overwritten the place on the drive where the data had been, rendering it less recoverable.
If Word created cached copies of the file as it was being worked on, it's likely good data recovery tools would be able to recover the document in all its versions and stages.
Finally, if you're dealing with a motivated data recovery attack by a nation-state level actor, it really doesn't matter: They'll get the data back.
This is all a reason why the correct way to run a Secure Erase tool is to clear all your temp files, and then have it wipe all the drive's free space.

"Finally, if you're dealing with a motivated data recovery attack by a nation-state level actor, it really doesn't matter: They'll get the data back." Citation needed. Data is not always recoverable.
